# Reading two points from dummy image and calculating distance using LinkedList C#/Java

Tags: java, c#, dictionary, structure

I've got a general idea from teacher to use a LinkedList which stores Linkedlist. I've connected 3 different linkedlists to 1 main linkedlist showing sub routes on a map.

I'm stuck at connecting the child nodes of a linked list to the child of other linkedlist. Keep in mind that I've to find the distance between those routes. I've been thinking for a long time, had a search on google too but I found nothing. No idea this time in my mind for approaching near to the possible logic. The route is as follows.
[http://imgur.com/a/zYGdu](https://imgur.com/a/zYGdu)
The red ones are creating problem for me if I go later for finding the distance, How will I approach it?

**Notice that the main linked list adds linkedlists in it as generic.**
 Is there any other approach which can be used. I'll use google maps for finding distance between these points one by one ad implementing it to each of the nodes. :( This is what comes in my mind.

Comment: If you are interested, you can use graph databse like neo4j https://neo4j.com/
Implementing connected nodes will be very easy

Comment: @staszek Is there any LinkedList process in neo4j.

Comment: No replies yet?